# Parser single line XML in iOS

Tags: ios, xml

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>
```

I am trying to read if the boolean is true or false but I cannot seem to find the answer. Maybe I am overlooking something very simple.

Here it is my iOS code:

```
- (void) startParsing:(NSURL *) dataReceived{
    NSLog(@"StartPasing started");
    NSXMLParser *responseParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]
                                  initWithContentsOfURL:dataReceived];
    responseParser.delegate = self;

    [responseParser parse];
    [responseParser release];
    [dataReceived release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
   attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

   NSLog(@"Parser started");    

   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"boolean"]) {
      NSLog(@"Found boolean");

      //I'M NOT SURE HOW TO READ THE VALUE INSIDE MY ELEMENT. 
   }
}
```

My code finds the element boolean just fine but then I cannot get the data from the element. I'm pretty sure this is simple issue and I much appreciate some help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using NSXMLParser and implementing NSXMLParserDelegate, you'll need to implement the method `-parser:foundCharacters:` so that it accumulates characters in a mutable string or other appropriate storage area. Then, when your `-parser:didEndElement:` method is called, you can look at the accumulated string and interpret it as you like. In this case, you'd probably just compare it to @"true".